# How do I display a second image after a specific line of dialogue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a game, where once you click a button, lines of text appear, basically telling a story. I already have an image but I want after a specific line of text to display a second one. I literally have tried everything but it doesn't work...

Code:

```js
var objects = [
    "The rain goes clickety clack tack. It was a cold night and a ruthful glimmer of azure pervaded the skies, which were dormantly laid above the cosmopolitan city. The children quietly wept under tattered rags and the grown ups began celebrating on the filth-stained juice joints, while the Plenilune was shining brightly upon them, giving an everlasting impression of cruel romanticism.",
    "Me and Mary went on a ride with the new red car through the woods. We had an argument about Helena. And then an accident happened. The car crashed. I-I hope she's dead.",
    "I wandered the woods and the memories slowly faded away. The insects were buzzing and the birds were chirping. As I was walking towards the forest's insides, I came across a group of people mourning over a mutilated body."
    ];
    
    function toggleFullScreen(elem) {
        if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
            if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
                elem.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
                elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        } else {
            if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                document.cancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    const paragraph = document.getElementById("doThis");
    const writeSpeed = 30;
    let letterIndex = 0;
    let objectsIndex = 0;
    
    function write() {
      const sentence = objects[objectsIndex];
      if (letterIndex > sentence.length) {
        letterIndex = 0;
        objectsIndex++;
        return;
      }
      paragraph.innerHTML += sentence.charAt(letterIndex);
      letterIndex++;
      setTimeout(write, writeSpeed);
    }
    
    function help() {
      paragraph.innerHTML = "";
      write();
    };
```

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  position:center;
  background-color:lightblue;
  width: 3.5%;
}

#doThis {
    text-indent: 50px;
    color:white;
    font:Bahnschrift SemiLIght;
    font-size: 4;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
  
 #doThis::after {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

#doThis::after {
  animation: blink 1.5s steps(2) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body> 
    
    <center><img src = "Caniglia-Image-07_Karl-Liebknecht_Kollwitz-1-1024x663.jpg"><id= "img"></center>

 

     <input type="button" value="Fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen(document.body)">

    <div class = "form">
        <button onclick="help();">click</button>
        <p id="doThis" data-index="-1"></p>
    </div>
    
    <script src = "lines.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your codepen link goes to stackoverflow's front page. Update the link. Alternetively you can post a runnable snippet with the `<>` button directly here in StackOverflow.

Comment: Hello, I apologize for the inconvenience it's my first time posting here.

Comment: You ought to follow the guidelines: **Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.** - that'¨s because if the codepen goes away. this question doesn't make sense to future readers

Comment: @PeterKrebs  I fixed it. Again sorry for the delay. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Now you made the link not clickable. Remove the brackets around it - or remove the link entirely now, since we have a snippet. You can use the preview when editing to see if something works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function write() {
  const sentence = options[optionsIndex];
  if (letterIndex > sentence.length) {
    letterIndex = 0;
    optionsIndex++;
    return;
  }
  if (optionsIndex === 2 && letterIndex === 0) { // For the paragraph where you want it entered
    // Your code here, for example:
    paragraph.innerHTML += '<div><img src="image.png" /></div>';
  }
  paragraph.innerHTML += sentence.charAt(letterIndex);
  letterIndex++;
  setTimeout(write, writeSpeed);
}
```

Comment: Hello, perhaps I applied it wrong but when I tried your suggested code the buttons didn't respond at all...

Comment: Probably means that there is syntax error. The `<div><img src....</div>` part wasn't in quotes, so that is edited and fixed now.

Comment: The second image display worked. Thank you so much! Now, do you know by any chance how I can replace the image in the html window with the second one after a specific line of text? Cause I just realize I worded my question wrong... I'm sorry for the confusion I'm not as fluent with english as I wish.

Comment: You should ask that as a new question.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Thank you!